# Need help identifying civilian small aircraft from old turkish movie

Tags: aviation-history

I need help identifying a plane from an older 1977 turkish comedy movie for a personal project, these are the best (and only) shots it can be seen.

Flyby [image: flyby]

Front Angle [image: front angle]

Close up cockpit outside [image: close up cockpit outside]

Answer (score 8):

It is a Cessna 188 crop duster. The giveaway is the shape of the cooling air inlets on either side of the prop, which are "Cessna-shaped", as opposed to those on the similar Piper Pawnee which are rounded.

Comment: Yep that's it nice catch.

Comment: This answer is a bit short but nevertheless correct.

Comment: @PeterKämpf, detail added! -NN